# Achieving polymorphism with smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to accomplish polymorphism via smart pointer. With raw pointers, you'd have a `Base*` as an argument type and pass in an address of the child class in the caller but I am having trouble with smart pointers.

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Child: public Base
{
    public:
    void Bar() override{}
};

class Random
{
    public:
    void Foo(std::shared_ptr<Base>& ptr){}
};

int main()
{
    Random random;
    Child<int> derived;
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<Child<int>>(std::move(derived));
    random.Foo(ptr);
}
```

With this, I get an error

> :45:16: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'shared_ptr' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'shared_ptr>'

Comment: but a shared_ptr is created out of it which is a pointer no?

Comment: does `Foo` really need to take a reference? If it took a const reference or a value the conversion would be automatic: https://godbolt.org/z/TvG1YGz1b

Comment: 1. Don't pass the shared_ptr pointer by  reference. 2. Add a (default if necessary) virtual dtor to `Base`.

Comment: why does shared_ptr supposed to be a const reference for it to work?

Comment: It doesn't. It can also be by-value. Anything to force a conversion should work, provided the classes are setup correctly.

Comment: I mean why does non const reference not work?

Comment: you can only bind related types to a non-const reference, `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>` are not related even if `A` and `B` are related. A const reference or value allows a temporary value to be created and therefore allows a converting constructor to create an object of the correct type

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for saving me the typing :-P

Comment: Why does `Random::Foo` care, specifically, that it gets a `shared_ptr<Base>` and not a `Base*` or a `Base&`? Does it actually matter who owns the underlying object for the purposes of that function?

Comment: @NathanPierson prolly to handle a case if the  `Derived*` objects that it will store (in a list etc) goes out of scope in the caller, what happens to it. With raw pointers, it will certainly become a dangling reference

Comment: @AlanBirtles which temporary gets created and why? is `ptr ` a temporary?

Comment: There is no temporary created in your code because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. It's very unlikely that a non-const reference to a shared pointer is what you actually need